# Factorial digit sum (without BigInt) C++

Tags: c++, factorial

I am trying to figure out how to solve this problem (Project Euler):

> n! means n × (n − 1) × ... × 3 × 2 × 1
>
> For example, 10! = 10 × 9 × ... × 3 × 2 × 1 = 3628800, and the sum of
>   the digits in the number 10! is 3 + 6 + 2 + 8 + 8 + 0 + 0 = 27.
>
> Find the sum of the digits in the number 100!

Using BigInt is not an option, I am trying to figure out how to implement a solution using only c++.

I thought maybe splitting the big numbers to an array of about 7 digit's long or something like that and then deal with them but i still cant figure out how to do this either..

thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you considered writing your own BigInt class?

Comment: Actually no :)

But i want to find out if there is a way to solve this without using a BigInt class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
#include "iostream"
#include "vector"

int n,remainder,sum;
int main ()
{   
    std::vector <int> digits(5000);    
    std::cin>>n;    
    digits[0]=1;
    digits[1]=1;
    for (int k=2;k<n+1;k++) {
        for (int i=1;i<=digits[0];i++) {
            digits[i]=digits[i]*k+remainder;
            remainder=0;
            if (digits[i]>9) {
                remainder=digits[i]/10;
                digits[i]%=10;
                if (i==digits[0])
                digits[0]++;
            }
        }
    }   
    for (int i=digits[0];i>=1;i--)
        sum+=digits[i];
    std::cout<<sum;
}
```

Comment: Few suggestions: Using `using namespace std` is a bad practice, use better names for variables and define variables inside `for`'s condition `for (int k=2;k<n+1;k++)`

Comment: @GabrielL. LOL, didn't see AbbaShareen solution.

Comment: Please do not post complete solutions to Euler problems. See http://projecteuler.net/about : "It is often through the best of intentions in wishing to share our insights so that others can enjoy that moment too. Sadly, however, that will not be the case for your readers. Real learning is an active process and seeing how it is done is a long way from experiencing that epiphany of discovery. Please do not deny others what you have so richly valued yourself."